# error using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have a table (created by php) whose last colum has input boxes in each of it cells:
php:

```
echo "<table id='booklist'><tr>
                         <th>Edit</th>
                         <th class='coursename'><a href='#' class='Course_Name'>Course Name</a></th>
                         <th class='startdate'><a href='#' class='Start_Date'>Start Date</a></th>
                         <th class='booktitle'><a href='#' class='Book_Title'>Book Title</></th>
                         <th class='bookauthor'><a href='#' class='Book_Author'>Book Author</a></th>
                         <th class='bookisbn'><a href='#' class='Book_Isbn'>Book ISBN</a></th>
                     </tr>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        { 
            echo    "<tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox'></input></td>
                        <td class='coursename'>" . $row['Course Name'] . "</td>
                        <td class='startdate'>" . $row['Start Date'] . "</td>
                        <td class='booktitle'>" . $row['Book Title']. "</td>
                        <td class='author'>" . $row['Book Author']. "</td>
                        <td class='isbn'><input class='ISBN_number' type='text' value='' size='13' maxlength='13'></input></td> 
                  </tr>";                   
        }               
echo "</table>";
```

I am trying to make a jquery function that does an ajax call to validate the content and if valid, to put a picture of a checkmark. Here is the jquery:

```
//validates a manually inputed ISBN number   
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ISBN_number").change(function(){
        var isbnNum = $(this).val();
        console.log("isbnNum = " . isbnNum);
        $.get("validate_isbn.php", {isbn: isbnNum},
            function(answer) 
            {                   
                console.log(answer);
                if (answer == true)
                {
                    $(this).after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
                }
                else 
                {

                }
            });

    });
```

The ajax calls validate_isbn.php and returns a true or false (and I know that file works, I have used it in other situations). But when I put a value in the input box nothing happens. None of my console.logs print out, all I get is the following message: "event.layerX and event.layerY are broken and deprecated in WebKit. They will be removed from the engine in the near future." I am not sure what this means and what is wrong with my code.

Comment: I think the change event fires when the element loses focus for input elements. Did you try clicking somewhere else on the page after you modify the value, or do you want it to work even if the element doesn't lose focus ?

Comment: No, I know how the change function works. I did click on the page (and the input box lost focus) and nothing happened (except for that error I mentioned).

Comment: `$(this)` won't equal the `<input>` that triggered the change event, I think.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, I think I have done things similar to this in other situations... If it doesn't, what else would I do?

Comment: The error is unrelated, you will only notice it on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to suffer from a few minor errors. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/YfDPb/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ISBN_number").change(function() {
        $this = $(this); // store the current 'this'
        var isbnNum = $this.val();
        console.log("isbnNum = "+isbnNum); // + not . to concatenate strings in JS
        $.get("validate_isbn.php", { // make sure this is the correct relative path
            isbn: isbnNum
        }, function(answer) {
            console.log($this);
            if (answer==='true') { // answer will be a string of text, not a boolean
                $this.after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
            } else {
                $this.after("nope"); // to verify that something's happening
            }
        });// end callback
    });//end change
});//end ready
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The comments you made were useful, but they didn't work... Luckily I found the issue myself. The problem was that I was using the .ready function, while I really needed to use .delegate, since the selector (.ISBN_number) is dynamically created by ajax and doesn't exist when the code is first run.

Answer (score -1):

An error has been occurred during the whole JS run. Install FireBug and go to Console tab to see what's happening wrong.

Comment: As my experience, every time a JS code doesn't running, a mistake has been made by the programmer. It's really true, I tested it hundred times!

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trying to be clever or not, but as an answer, this isn't helpful at all.

Comment: @mblase75, It's related to my business not yours. :)